# Displaying indefinite Progress bar using Jquery

Tags: java, jquery, html, css

I need to upload a file through a webservice call.. So, basically I have build a front end application to get the file and transfer to the apache webserver..Once its in the webserver, I call the webservice to load to a external systems..I know its a 2 step process but we can't help as we have security issues...

Now, I want to display a progress bar but not showing the percentage because I really don't know how long will it take for the service to complete...

Is there a any progress bar that shows the files are being transferred and not how much percentage....

Comment: Well you are looking for a loading gif

Comment: When I wanted to show a loading indicator I also found a gif was simplest and most effective method. Searching for ajax loading indicators and gifs led me to this which I thought would be helpful: http://ajaxload.info/